# Update SharePoint Online list when new row is added to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, o365-flow

So, I'm working on this project where my client wants to send forms with simple yes and no questions to their customers, adding each customer to a SharePoint list when the form is submitted. The customers gets different scores depending on their answers.
My client is using Office 365 and wants it all "out of the box".

What I have done i I've created a form (with Forms) that adds a row with the answers and the score to a new row on an Excel spreadsheet every time one hits the submit button on the form. So far, so good. What i need help with is exporting and updating the spreadsheet to a SharePoint list. I have been looking at Flow and think that's the way to go, but I'm in over my head. 
Suggestions? Help? Tips?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well well, after 5 minutes of searching I've found beautiful out-of-the-box solution leveraging Microsoft Form, Flow and SharePoint apps:[Microsoft Forms and Flow - Leveraging Real-Time Survey Results in the Cloud](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Forms/Microsoft-Forms-and-Flow-Leveraging-Real-Time-Survey-Results-in/td-p/81028)

So basically:

1. Create survey with Microsoft Forms
2. Create Microsoft SharePoint list with columns which will map to your survey question/answers
3. Use Microsoft Flow `When a new response is submitted` trigger
4. Add Microsoft SharePoint `Create item` action connected to Flows trigger and map your question to columns

**Read the article, it contains more useful information.**

Comment: Yes, that looks good and all, but it doesn't really help me. Since I need to use the Excel spreadsheet to calculate scores based on answers I cant connect the form with SharePoint directly. Forms in Office is quite limited, and I don't even know if I'll use them in the end, but might build my own form with Power Apps. If this happens I think it's best if Excel is connected with SharePoint and then I'll just connect the new form to Excel, without messing with the rest of the project.